# Disposing UnitOfWork

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, prism, dbcontext

My question is how to dispose of the UnitOfWork, in a desktop app using EF6, Prism Unity, MVVM, WPF and a local database.  I want to create and dispose of the UnitOfWork (including its DbContext) each time a view is created.

When the user selects a menu item, the SubMenuViewModel activates the selected view.  For instance, if I select AdrTypeView, SubMenuViewModel does this:

```
using (CallingCreateUoWASync())
{
RegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionNames.MainRegionLeft, typeof(AdrTypeView));
}
```

Prism's RegisterViewWithRegion method both creates and activates the view.  I am creating the EntityUnitOfWork asynchronously from the SubMenuViewModel so that the DbContext can be created while the views are loading.

```
private async Task CreateUoWASync()
    {
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
         EntityUnitOfWork MyUnitOfWork = new EntityUnitOfWork();

     });
    }
```

After the AdrTypeView is displayed, then if I select another view from the SubMenuViewModel, the AdrTypeView disappears from the region, making way for a new view in the region, by reason of the AdrTypeViewModel implementing IRegionMemberLifetime, with KeepAlive set to false.

The problem is that the instance of MyUnitOfWork is still around, and it references the AdrType repositories.

---

EDIT:  I think the answer to my question has more to do with how to change from a singleton instance of EntityUnitOfWork to creating new instances of EntityUnitOfWork for each view.

I removed from the moduleinit class the container registration for EntityUnitOfWork, ie.

```
     Container.RegisterType<EntityUnitOfWork, EntityUnitOfWork("EntityUnitOfWork");
```

So I am not doing any Container registration at all for EntityUnitOfWork.  Still, the singleton instance of EntityUnitOfWork remains after I change and dispose a view.  I can see the old values when I do this:

```
 EntityUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<EntityUnitOfWork>();
```

So how do I dispose of EntityUnitOfWork using the Container.RegisterType or Container.RegisterInstance?  I would probably prefer to programmatically dispose of the instance.  Thank you.

Comment: Why the hell are you using a Task to instantiate your Unit of Work?

Comment: Also, IRegionMemberLifetime is only used when using Prim's navigation framework.

Comment: Tseng, can you tell me another way to do it asynchronously?  Like I said, I want to create the UnitOfWork while the views are also loading because creating DbContext is not the quickest process.

Comment: IRegionMemberLifetime works to clear the region for another view.  Is there some better way to clear the region automatically when changing views?

Comment: Creating Entity Frameworks DbContext is a quick operation. Initializing DbContext has almost no costs, unless you do some funky stuff like queries inside your derived class, like executing query, which is a no-go. Construction of classes should be fast, if you do something that takes very long time, you do it wrong. Have you tested it?

Comment: It is not just the DbContext,  creating that and the repositories takes about three seconds, which is a long time to some people on the computer.

Comment: Your repositories are designed wrong. The constructor shouldn't do ANY blocking operation at all. Don't **ever** do any queries or any blocking operation in the constructor

Comment: The EntityUnitOfWork constructor is not doing any async operations.  The CallingCreateUoWASync is awaiting.

Answer (score 1):

The dispose method is called implicitly when you use `using`.

```
// Context gets disposed when leaving the using block
using (var uow = CallingCreateUoWASync())
{
    // do something with uow
    uow.Add(...);
    uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

If you don't use `using` then you have to explicitly call `.Dispose()` Method.

Comment: Right, that is understood.  Even though SubMenuViewModel has IRegionMemberLifetime KeepAlive set to false, for some reason, the MyEntityUnitOfWork is still not getting cleared when I select another view.  When I select another view, I can see the old values in debugger with:      EntityUnitOfWork _unitOfWork = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<EntityUnitOfWork>();

Comment: First, just because you dispose an object it do not mean it immediately frees the memory. Disposing only frees unmanaged memory (pointers, file handles, etc.), the managed objects get disposed next time the GC executes. Second, you shouldn't tie the lifetime of your UoW to a viewmodel but rather bind it to an command (let's say you have ViewModel with a list of users. You do your changes, then click on the "Save" button. Inside the save button you get the an instance of your uow, add/update your entries, then call save and get it auto-disposed when leaving the using block)

Comment: EDIT:  I had a typo in my question, the method name does match the using statement, ie. private async Task CallingCreateUoWASync().   For each data file that the user may select for viewing & editing, there is a separate using statement.  The code I have should work, no?